# htaccess not working in my URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want people to be able to access my website with a URL like this:

```
snappy.com
```

But my real URL is like this:

```
snappy.com/system/core/loader
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^snappy.com snappy.com/system/core/loader [L, QSA]
```

How do I redirect people to the correct URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to redirect your  site from

```
http://snappy.com/system/core/loader
```

to

```
http://snapy.com
```

then you can use below **.htaccess** rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^snapy\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.snapy\.com$
  RewriteRule ^system\/core\/loader\/$ "http\:\/\/snapy\.com\/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```